# Как присоединиться к MySQL PHP?

Tags: mysql

ВСем привет. Выложу простейший код , почему-то не могу подключиться к базе (имя базы и таблицы указаны верно). В интернете не нашел инфы на такой случай, подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем тут ошибка?Нужно просто добавить данные с input в таблицу

index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<?php require_once('databaseapp.php');?>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The HTML5 Herald</title>
  <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
  <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <form method = "post">
        <label>Type your nickname so you can leave some messages in the sidebar</label>
        <input type = "text" name = "nickname" id ="nick" placeholder = "type your nickname" required>
    </form>
  <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

DATABASE:

```
<?php
$nickname = $_POST['nickname'];
$dbserver = '127.0.0.1';
$dbuser = 'mysql';
$dbpass = 'mysql';
$dbname = 'testapp';
$dbconnect = mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);


if(mysqli_connect){
    echo "We all good Mike";
}
else {
    echo "We all fucked Mike";
    }


if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
    echo $nickname;
    /*$record ="INSERT INTO nufack (nickname) VALUES ('".$nickname."')";*/
    $record ="INSERT INTO `nufack` (`nickname`) VALUES ('".$_POST['nickname']."')";
    $rec = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $record);
    if($rec){
        echo "success!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Database fucked up!";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysqli-connect.php , http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php а лучше сразу http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Comment: https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/jquery-serialize-form Прочитав это ты решишь, свою проблему. Про данный код, не могу тебе ничего сказать. Так как такой метод очень устарел.

Comment: Где в этой статье хоть одно слово про подключение к БД?

Comment: В твоей статье я не нашёл инфы про insert data , но за последний мануал спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Используйте для проверки следующий код

```
<?php
  if( !$dbconnect = mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname)) {
  die('No connection: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
  }
 ?>
```

Или

```
<?php
  $dbconnect = mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

 // Check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
?>
```

Comment: Я проверил так, как ты сказал на ошибки, он подключается к база, но все равно данные nickname не вводит в таблицу

Comment: Установите в дескрипторе <form> атрибут action. А так же внутри формы (до закрывающего тега) установите ещё один <input type="submit">

Comment: Ещё как вариант
Сделай так: (инструкция к google chrome, хотя другие браузеры тоже умеют)

1) Жми Ctrl+shift+i

2) Перейди во вкладку Network

3) Нажми свой сабмит и увидишь там файл который является обработчиком на сервере.

4) Кликни по нему и смотри вкладку Headers

5) В самом низу найди Form Data вот здесь и увидишь что случилось и где ошибка спряталась

Comment: Form data в самом низу пустая, там только написано : nickname : ghhfd   Submit : submit

Comment: Отлично. Дело за малым.Отправляй такой запрос к базе:

$rec = $dbconnect->query("INSERT INTO `nufack` (`nickname`) VALUES ('$nickname')");

Comment: Короче, оказывается проблема была в том, что одна из колонок не имела default значения, я все проставил и заработало! Спасибо за помощь